# Select2 does not complete the model's value (returns null as property value)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I use select2 with id and name of one of properties in my model.
the data source is a view bag. (it works correctly)

I want to set the selected value as default based on another dropdown change.  (it works correctly, too)

but after the form submit, the value of the property is null

(if I select the dropdown value by clicking it works well)

In my Controller I have:

```
 ViewBag.DefaultAirport = defualtAirport.Value; // for example: "1"
```

and in my view I have:

```
 <select id="Destination" name="Destination" class="select2" style="width: 100%; padding: 3px;">
                            @foreach (var airport in (List<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Airports)
                            {
                                <option value="@airport.Value">
                                    @airport.Text
                                </option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

and in scripts:

```
  function setOrginDistination(elementValue) {
    if (elementValue === "@((int) Enums.FlightDirection.Arrival)") {
        $("#Destination option[value='@Html.Raw(ViewBag.DefaultAirport)']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

the selection works because I can see it in browser, and when I use debugging mode in browser really the option is selected.

Comment: what's the down-vote's reason?

Comment: Not related but generate the dropdownlist correctly using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Destination, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Airports, new { class = "select2" })` and set the value using `var default = @ViewBag.DefaultAirport; $('#Destination').val(default );`

Comment: Have you tried to select the value programatically? Like $('#Destination').select2(<value>).trigger('change') ?

Comment: I see no reasons for down-vote

Comment: yes I did it. the main problem was that before setting the default airport as selected, I was disabled the drop down because I didn't want to allow the user to change that. I found out disabling the element, causes to use null value, even if it has accepted the selected property. I mean the element has selected item, but since it's disable does not use that selected item as value.